# Bootstrap radio buttons awkward in column context, not lining up with other columns in row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a screen shot of as close as I could get with the radio buttons lining up with the other columns in a row:

[image: Picture of radio buttons in context of form]

The issue is that the Radio buttons are not lining up horizontally (not equal space top and bottom). It isn't terrible, but it just looks awkward.  It would be nice if there was some way to make the radio buttons really seem like they are a part of the form.  Maybe make them bigger, take up more space in their container, and ensure that the radio buttons/labels are aligned vertically.

Here is the relevant code in the form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class='form-group'>
            <%= f.label :web %> 
            <%= f.text_field :web, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class='form-group'>
            <%= f.label :business_contact, "Business Contact" %>  
            <%= f.text_field :business_contact, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class='text-center'>
            <br>
            <%= f.label :gender, "Gender: " %> 
            <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Male', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Male' || @employer.gender == 'male'), class: "radio-inline" %>
            <%= f.label :male %>
            <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Female', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Female' || @employer.gender == 'female'), class: "radio-inline" %>
            <%= f.label :female %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this and called it good:

[image: my radio button solution]

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div >
            <%= f.label :gender %> <br>
            <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Male', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Male' || @employer.gender == 'male'), class: "radio-inline" %>
            <%= f.label :male %>
              <span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Female', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Female' || @employer.gender == 'female'), class: "radio-inline" %>
            <%= f.label :female %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class='text-center'>
        <br>
        <!-- Instead add a span here below "<br>" -->
        <span style="margin-top:5px"> <!-- start here like this -->
        <%= f.label :gender, "Gender: " %> 
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Male', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Male' || @employer.gender == 'male'), class: "radio-inline" %>
        <%= f.label :male %>
        <%= f.radio_button :gender, 'Female', checked: (@employer.gender == 'Female' || @employer.gender == 'female'), class: "radio-inline" %>
        <%= f.label :female %>
  </span> <!-- and instead end it here -->
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: That should pull your text in the col-sm-4 to the left(still as text-center), and add a small margin of 5px to the element giving it a bit of spacing from the top, from the left, and from the bottom and right. If you want greater control, margin is sized in 4 parameters as top-right-bottom-left.

So Margin: 5px 5px 0px 3px; would give you 5px top, 5 px to right 0px below and 3px to the left, or you can give 2 parameters to margin:  5px 2px; That means 5 px top and bottom, 2px left and right. Lastly, as I gave it to you margin: 5px; Means 5px on all sides.

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work.  I already have it aligned vertically (equal space on left and right sides).  The problem is aligning it horizontally (equal space on top and bottom sides).

Comment: Yes, but you do have it aligned correctly top to bottom.  You could attempt a span around and it add a slight excess of top-margin value to the element.  As what you have displayed is exact center in regards to the vertical elements in that row.  Note that "Business Example" AND the text input below it are 1 element in that row.  So your Gender element is aligned perfectly to the middle of those elements, which combined as 1 column/row.  - Try using only the addition style attribute on that particular element, and adding some top-margin.

Comment: See the code changes I just made.  Just use the span with the style="margin-top:5px;" under the break, just above the Gender elements.  Adjust the "5px" as needed to get the correct centering you desire.  Assuming what you want is the Gender + Radio buttons to center similarly to the middle of the text box.  That, or adjust your "<br>" element to be below the "GENDER:" text value, and the radio buttons should then align themselves somewhat similarly for male/female buttons to the text box for the "Business Contact" column.